# HTML / XML - Fictional tag / pseudo tag, what are they? Are they valid HTML, XML?

Tags: html, xml

I saw some examples in CSS in w3.org that uses what they called fictional tags. Please see example:

```
<P:first-letter>
</P:first-letter>
```

They look like asp.net's tags. What are they exactly? Are these tags valid HTML? Are these tags valid XML? Can I use them? Can somebody illuminate me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#x55) article, I would say that these fictional tags are just tags that help you understand what a certain css property actually does.

For the given example, they are explaining how the p:first-letter{} affects the p element - it changes the style of the *first letter* in the element. You could interpret this as if the first letter of the p element had 'invisible'/'virtual'/'fictional' tags around it, which define a separate style for it - this is what they mean by fictional tags.

Bottom line, they are not valid tags, they are just a means to describe a concept in the tutorials.

As for the pseudo elements, [this](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/pseudoelements/) article explains it quite well.